# Java GPA logic error

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a simple GPA calculation program in Java, but I have a logic error somewhere causing the answers to be incorrect.

My first test values are a grade of 87.3% and credit value of 3, and a grade of 74.2% and credit of 3.0. I'm getting an answer of 4.0, if I print the `gradePointTotal` or should be named weighted credit value, I'm getting 24.0 instead of 21.0 for those.

```
public class lab5{

     public static void main(String[] args){
             double gradeTotal = 0;
             double gradeAverage = 0;
             double creditValueTotal = 0;
             double gradePoint = 0;
             double gradePointTotal = 0;
             int counter = 1;

             Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
             Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
             String repeat;
             do {
             System.out.print("Enter a grade: ");
             double grade = input.nextDouble();
             System.out.print("Enter credit value: ");
             double creditValue = input.nextDouble();
             System.out.print("Enter Another course ? (YES/NO) ");
             repeat = input2.next();
             gradeTotal += grade;
             gradeAverage = gradeTotal / counter;
             creditValueTotal += creditValue;

             if (gradeAverage >= 80)
            gradePoint = 4.0;
     else if (gradeAverage >= 75)
            gradePoint = 3.5;
     else if (gradeAverage >= 70)
            gradePoint = 3.0;
     else if (gradeAverage >= 65)
            gradePoint = 2.5;
     else if (gradeAverage >= 60)
            gradePoint = 2.0;
     else if (gradeAverage >= 50)
            gradePoint = 1.0;
     else if (gradeAverage < 50)
            gradePoint = 0.0;

     gradePointTotal += gradePoint * creditValue;

     counter++;
             }
             while("YES".equalsIgnoreCase(repeat) || "y".equalsIgnoreCase(repeat));

             double gradePointAverage = gradePointTotal / creditValueTotal;

     System.out.println(gradePointAverage);



     }

}
```

Comment: please be honest and tag your question as homework if appropriate.

Comment: Anything over 80 is a 4.0?  I'm pretty sure at my highschool we had to get at least 90 or 95...

Comment: Also, you shouldn't need two input scanners.  And please break up your code into more methods - that should help when finding issues.

Answer (score 1):

There is, to start, a lot wrong here. You are learning, so that is fine. The thing to remember about programming though, is you write lines of code for a reason.. Each line of code has a specific reason to exist. Looking at your code, I see some confusion. You don't understand what each line of code is doing. For example, you have input, and input 2. Why? (Hint, you are probably confused about what System.in does).

What you need to do before you write any code is to write an english description of what you want to do. It should look like this:

//step 1: repeatedly ask for course score and GPA until the user is done entering them

//step 2: add all the scores the user entered together. Divide by the number of entries.

//Step 3: Print out the output

Then, you can start flushing out the details of each stem

//Step 1a) get a handle to the command line user interface for grabbing data (System.in)
.. etc

Basically, you start with a high level outline, then flush out the details.. The final details are your lines of code. This has the benefit of making self commenting code, so your instructors and other persons can read not just *what* you are doing, but *why* you are doing it. You can also find the right function call or system resource to do what you want, rather than having some resource you don't know what it does and trying to make it do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the line where you calculate `gradeAverage` .Dividing the given grade by your `counter` , or even having a counter in the first place, doesn't really make sense to me. Also, use `grade` in the condition of each of your if-else-if's.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to take the average of the gradePointAverage.

```
CreditValue Total = CreditValue;
GradePointTotal = GradePoint*CreditValue;
double gradePointAverage += gradePointAverage + (GradePointTotal/CreditValueTotal);
double GPA = gradePointAverage / count;
```

By not incrementing the credit total and the gradepoint total, they get re-assigned every time the loop is re-entered.  However, incrementing the gradePointAverage allows you to keep adding onto it.  Then you take the average to get the average gpa.